# changing units in mod files for NEURON

Tags: neuron-simulator

How to change units in a mod file so that after running `neuoConstract` the units will be saved?

```
units:  0.001 sec
units:  1
The units of the previous two expressions are not conformable
 at line 75 in file C:/Users/miria/Desktop/neuro/neuroConstruct_1.7.2/nCexamples/Ex4_HHcell/generatedNEURON/CurrentClampExt.mod
            beginNextCycle = beginNextCycle + (del + dur)<<ERROR>>
```

I have tried to change with Notepad++ but the changes can not be saved for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

The **error** that you are getting here is the result of **unit mismatch** between the **RHS and LHS** of the equation:

`beginNextCycle = beginNextCycle + (del + dur)`

in `CurrentClampExt.mod` file. `beginNextCycle`, `del` and `dur` should have the same units e.g. millisecond.

For **editing** the `CurrentClampExt.mod` file, you can use Notepad++ or any other text editor. The constants/variables for equation are declared most likely in the mod file's **ASSIGNED** or **PARAMETER** block. Make sure that the these variables follow a unit. For example:

```
ASSIGNED {
          dur (ms)
          del (ms)
}
```

where (ms) refers to millisecond.

You can **check the units** of mod files by using NEURON simulator's '**modlunit**' feature. See here for more details: https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/docs/nmodl/mswin.html

Once you are done with unit correction, then compile the mod file(s) using nrnivmodl (as shown [in the above link](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/docs/nmodl/mswin.html)). If there are no errors, then try to run the code using `neuroConstruct`.